# Spotting Patterns with R

Tags: r

I have some very simple data;

```
id <- c("jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec")
outcome <- c("FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE")

df_example <- data.frame(id = id, outcome= outcome)
```

The challenge I have is I am trying to spot patterns of (n) TRUE values in a row. If I do, then I want to add a third variable 'pattern' and add TRUE to each row within that pattern.

Hoping someone can support.

I've been trying group_by() and fill() without much success

What I'd like to achieve is...

```
id <- c("jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec")
outcome <- c("FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE")
pattern <- c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE")

df_example <- data.frame(id = id, outcome= outcome, pattern = pattern)
```

Comment: How is the pattern defined? What rules govern it?

Comment: your edit doesn't answer my question

Comment: Look into run length encoding using `rle()`

Answer (score 2):

As PaulStaffordAllen suggested, run-length encoding (`rle`) works here:

```r
r <- rle(df_example$outcome)
r
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:8] 1 1 1 1 2 3 1 2
#   values : chr [1:8] "FALSE" "TRUE" "FALSE" "TRUE" "FALSE" "TRUE" "FALSE" "TRUE"
```

Given this, we can find all lengths that are fewer than 3 and force them to be false.

```r
r$values[r$lengths < 3] <- "FALSE"
df_example$pattern2 <- inverse.rle(r)
df_example
#     id outcome pattern pattern2
# 1  jan   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
# 2  feb    TRUE   FALSE    FALSE
# 3  mar   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
# 4  apr    TRUE   FALSE    FALSE
# 5  may   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
# 6  jun   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
# 7  jul    TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
# 8  aug    TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
# 9  sep    TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
# 10 oct   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
# 11 nov    TRUE   FALSE    FALSE
# 12 dec    TRUE   FALSE    FALSE
```

(Note: you are working on strings, not boolean/logical values. If you are intending to treat it as boolean, you can fix it with `df_example$outcome <- (df_example$outcome == "TRUE")`. The `rle` code still works, albeit changing `<- "FALSE"` to `<- FALSE`.)